# Embedding a webview into another view

Tags: android, android-webview

I have in my application 2 views:

a. res/layout/main.xml - a standard view with 1 button

b. res/layout/web_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
         <WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I click the button on the first view(a), it loads the webview(b) and loads an url:

```
// click on the "Browser" button in view a
public void goToWebView(View view) {
        setContentView(R.layout.web_view);
        WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
```

All that is working fine, the url load well but the browser **is instantiated into its own view** (a third one, not b itself) and my goal is to use the Webview to show some HTML code into my application, not outside of it, in a separate browser.

Anyboyd any idea?

This is done using API level8/Android 2.2.

Thanks for your help.
Paul

Comment: This thing happened to me only when I was opening some urls, for which intent-listeners were registered. For example google chrome seems to register itself for opening `http://www.google.com`. When I tried any other domain `http://www.something.com` it would be open in the same view. Just FYI

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually I finally understood. Even if you programatically load the url with

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

you also have to mofify the default behaviour (which is opening an url in a new browser instance).
The previous code needs 2 enhancements.

```
// override default behaviour of the browser
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Then, set for the view which uses Webclient the new behaviour:

```
public void goToWebView(View view) {
        setContentView(R.layout.web_view);
        WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        // add the following line ----------
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
```

Comment: yes thats the thing. your question was confsuing actually. ur question shudve been regarding handling redirection in webview

Comment: Thank you @Paul. I finally found what I'm searching for two hours.

Comment: Hi, I was just looking for this. Thanks for the answer, I like to know how you got to know about this? I mean did you read about every class in Android code?

Comment: Hi @Harsha. Sincerely I don't remember exactly. I think I rechecked the documentation and some examples and figured it out from there.

Comment: Thanks, So basically I currently  need to learn android really well and be confident about it. So I am looking for ways to do that.

Comment: I'd suggest you check that your Java basics are well known. I came to Android from another language and it took me a while to write decent Java code. Other than that, Android's documentation is great and if you spend some time looking at some open source code, you'll be on right track. And take the time to read and understand the API documentation. It's worth it.