# Viewing Android Layout in Webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm new in Android Application. I am just wondering if there is a way to view a layout inside the webview? for example.

```
WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
String url = "Layout location or R.Layout.test";
webview.loadUrl(url);
```

It's just like except of Using Activity class to View a layout like this
setContentView(R.layout.test);

I'm trying to view the layout in a webview.

Any thoughts will be highly appreciated.

Comment: A web view is used to load a url, and nothing like a layout. Its defined.

Comment: what are you trying to do? you may get negative reputation for this kind of questions

Comment: I'm trying to load a layout into a WebView if possible.

Comment: You can only load HTML files into the webview.. Its similar like asking can i open Windows Explorer inside Chrome? lol

Comment: I guess this is possible. Because I already saw a tutorial for this long time a go and I try it. But now I can't find that link of tutorial and my files are all gone  =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you saw in the tutorial, I presume they may not be loading layouts **INTO** the `WebView` rather it may be `along with` the `WebView`.

In other words,you can actually use layouts similar to divs in a HTML.. you take a layout, add Webview into it and then add Buttons and other controls out side the webview tags as shown by lgw150.

**This may give one the impression that the buttons etc are inside the webview but they are actually not!** You can have something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

For more check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561709/opening-webview-not-in-new-browser) and [this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359197/embedding-a-webview-into-another-view).

Answer (score 0):

view a layout inside the webview?I dont understand clearly,below maybe is a example for you

```
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progWeb"
style="@style/progressbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:max="100"
android:visibility="invisible" />

<WebView
android:id="@+id/web"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/progWeb"
android:layout_marginTop="28dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

TO BE CLEAR, A WEB VIEW CAN'T BE USED TO LOAD LAYOUTS.

check this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.  The compiled application doesn't contain resource XML.  It is converted into an internal format:

http://www.atcomm.com.au/Atcomm-Underground/Java/Compiled-and-Noncompiled-Android-Resources.html

http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html